# opencl workitem run parallel

Tags: optimization, parallel-processing, kernel, workitem

asking about speed or optimize the code
the kernel for sobel edge detection for gray img
When I run the program without any process only show input video and output(same as input) the frame per secounds fps=70 but when process down to 20 (process using GPU kernel for sobel)

Does anyone have an idea of how to speed up this code? I used local memory instead of global memory but the change is small.
How can I make all work items process the image?

#### sobel kernel

```
__kernel void hello_kernel(const __global uchar *input, __global uchar *output,const uint width,const uint height)
{   
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);
    int index = width * y + x;
    float a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
    float8 v; 
    float sobelX = 0;
    float sobelY = 0;
    //if(index > width && index < (height*width)-width && (index % width-1) > 0 && (index % width-1) < width-1){
    a = input[index-1-width] * -1.0f;
    b =input[index-0-width] *  0.0f;
    c = input[index+1-width] * +1.0f;
    d = input[index-1] * -2.0f;
    e = input[index-0] *  0.0f;
    f = input[index+1] * +2.0f;
    g = input[index-1+width] * -1.0f;
    h = input[index-0+width] *  0.0f;
    i = input[index+1+width] * +1.0f;
    sobelX = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i;
    
    a = input[index-1-width] * -1.0f;
    b = input[index-0-width] * -2.0f;
    c = input[index+1-width] * -1.0f;
    d = input[index-1] * 0.0f;
    e = input[index-0] * 0.0f;
    f = input[index+1] * 0.0f;
    g = input[index-1+width] * +1.0f;
    h = input[index-0+width] * +2.0f;
    i = input[index+1+width] * +1.0f;
    sobelY = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i;
      
    output[index] = sqrt(pow(sobelX,2) + pow(sobelY,2));    
}
```

Comment: The code you have shown doesn't do anything useful, so it is unclear what your problem is.

Comment: the host code http://www.speedyshare.com/hnzKP/main.cpp
sorry cant update the topic

Comment: I have indented your code and attempted to make your question clearer. Please can you change the rest of it so that it makes more sense? It would be especially useful to change your title.